# How to assign a class property to textarea tag?

Tags: html, css

I have a text area tag, wanted to write water mark functionality. So, i have assigned a class (css) to that tag. but it is not getting recognised. if i write css style for the textarea ID it is working.

```
function renderhtml(subgrid_id, row_id) {debugger;

    var script = "<div style='margin-left:10px; margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px;'>";
    script += "<textarea cssClass=watermarkOn cols=20 id=txtCommentSection name=txtCommentSection rows=2>Type your comments here</textarea>";
    script += "<input type='image' id='image' src='../../Content/Images/commentIcon.png'/>";
    script += "</div>";

    return script;
}
```

This is the css style:

```
.watermarkOn{color: #CCCCCC; font-style: italic;width:800px; height:30px;  }
```

i have tried changing the class from "cssClass" to just "class" but still the style is not getting affected.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is the culprit.

```
 script += "<textarea cssClass=watermarkOn cols=20 id=txtCommentSection name=txtCommentSection rows=2>Type your comments here</textarea>";
```

It should be:

```
script += '<textarea class="watermarkOn" cols=20 id="txtCommentSection" name="txtCommentSection "rows=2>Type your comments here</textarea>';
```

Comment: Thanks Codrin Eugeniu, i have changed but still the stylesheet is not getting effected. But for ID i can set the style. Problem is i want class only. :(

Answer (score 3):

Use `textarea class="watermarkOn"` instead of `textarea cssClass=watermarkOn`

Comment: @suman, the code given works OK with the stylesheet in your question. The problem is most probably in a part of your code that was not disclosed. Please provide a complete standalone document (or its URL) that demonstrates the problem, and specify the browser(s) tested. By “standalone” I mean a simple HTML document, as opposite to the code in the question, which is part of code for generating part of HTML document.